# tkinter - show image overlay on a canvas image with mouse move

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, photoimage

I have two images that are the exact same size.  One is the base background image and the other image is an altered version of the background image.  I am trying to show a window of a static size (such as 100,100) of the altered image over the top of the background image where they line up wherever the mouse is moved.  Sort of a moving window overlaying the altered image over the base image.  I have been trying to modify some base code I found somewhere here on Stack Overflow, but can't seem to figure out how to modify it to get the desired result.  Please suggest an alternative method if you think I am going about this the wrong way, or also if there is a close example somewhere I have missed.  I am very new to tkinter.  Also, I have no need for the coordinate system shown in my image examples below.  Just the image alone is good.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from scipy.misc import imread

event2canvas = lambda e, c: (c.canvasx(e.x), c.canvasy(e.y))

# function to be called when mouse is moved
def move_window(event):
    # outputting x and y coords to console
    cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
    print("(%d, %d) / (%d, %d)" % (event.x, event.y, cx, cy))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    # loading background and altered image into numpy array.
    background_image_data = imread("images/original.png", mode="L")
    foreground_image_data = imread("images/altered.png", mode="L")

    # Here is where the mouse coordinates should be injected to move the window over the background image
    window_data = foreground_image_data[500:600, 500:600]
    background_image_data[500:600, 500:600] = window_data

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(background_image_data))
    canvas.create_image(0, 0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL), width=img.width(), height=img.height())

    test = canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", move_window)

    root.mainloop()
```

Background Image:
[image]

Altered Image:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually did almost all of it. You just need to reposition some of the things and add a few things here and there (I'm not going to do it in a clean way otherwise I have to change more stuff. You can do that yourself later to not have duplicate lines in your code):

1. Change this part of your code:

   ```
   # loading background and altered image into numpy array.
   background_image_data = imread("images/original.png", mode="L")
   foreground_image_data = imread("images/altered.png", mode="L")

   # Here is where the mouse coordinates should be injected to move the window over the background image
   window_data = foreground_image_data[500:600, 500:600]
   background_image_data[500:600, 500:600] = window_data

   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(background_image_data))
   canvas.create_image(0, 0,image=img,anchor="nw")
   canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL), width=img.width(), height=img.height())
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   # loading background and altered image into numpy array.
   background_image_data = imread("images/original.png", mode="L")
   foreground_image_data = imread("images/altered.png", mode="L")
   '''Shouldn't change the original background image because
   that way the changes will be permanent'''
   bg_img = background_image_data.copy() 
   # Here is where the mouse coordinates should be injected to move the window over the background image
   x,y,wh = (50,50,100)
   window_data = foreground_image_data[y:y+wh,x:x+wh]
   bg_img[y:y+wh,x:x+wh] = window_data
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(bg_img))
   canvas.create_image(0, 0,image=img,anchor="nw")
   canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL), width=img.width(), height=img.height())
   ```
2. Change `"<ButtonPress-1>"` to `"<Motion>"` so it would run by change of mouse position. Or change it to `"<B1-Motion>"` so it runs whenever you are holding down Left-Button and moving the mouse.
3. Change this:

   ```
   def move_window(event):
       cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   def move_window(event):
       global img
       cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
       x,y,wh = (int(cx),int(cy),100)
       window_data = foreground_image_data[y:y+wh,x:x+wh]
       bg_img = background_image_data.copy()
       bg_img[y:y+wh,x:x+wh] = window_data
       img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(bg_img))
       canvas.create_image(0, 0,image=img,anchor="nw")
   ```

And you're done! As you can see it's all your own code just moved around, and with a few spices. I haven't worked with canvas very much so I don't know if that last part will keep creating new image on top of the other or replacing an already existing one. So I don't know if it's the best code to use there, but it works.
You better clean this code up because as you can see a lot of the code from `move_window` is the same as it was before the mainloop
Good luck.

Comment: You made it look so simple!  Thanks!

Comment: Hey. I made a horrible mistake there which I fixed in my edit. I confused the mechanics of tkinter mainloop again! (happens every time I come back to tkinter!). You don't need the first_run thing at all. Just remove that and you'll be fine. The mainloop doesn't work like that!!!